# execute commands in a CoreOS cloud-config (e.g. to add swap)

Tags: digital-ocean, systemd, coreos, swapfile

I see that unlike the standard `cloud-config` file, there is no `runcmd` option in a CoreOS `cloud-config` file.  Currently, I enable swap on a CoreOS machine by adding the following to my `cloud-config`:

```
units:
    - name: swap.service
      command: start
      content: |
        [Unit]
        Description=Turn on swap

        [Service]
        Type=oneshot
        Environment="SWAPFILE=/1GiB.swap"
        RemainAfterExit=true
        ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/losetup -f ${SWAPFILE}
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh -c "/sbin/swapon $(/usr/sbin/losetup -j ${SWAPFILE} | /usr/bin/cut -d : -f 1)"
        ExecStop=/usr/bin/sh -c "/sbin/swapoff $(/usr/sbin/losetup -j ${SWAPFILE} | /usr/bin/cut -d : -f 1)"
        ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/sh -c "/usr/sbin/losetup -d $(/usr/sbin/losetup -j ${SWAPFILE} | /usr/bin/cut -d : -f 1)"

        [Install]
        WantedBy=local.target
```

Then after initializing my CoreOS image I have to ssh into the machine and run:

```
sudo fallocate -l 1024m /1GiB.swap && sudo chmod 600 /1GiB.swap \
&& sudo chattr +C /1GiB.swap && sudo mkswap /1GiB.swap

sudo reboot
```

before swap will be enabled (e.g. as evidenced by `top`).

It seems like I should be able to accomplish the latter commands in the `cloud-config` file itself, but I'm not clear on how I can run such commands without a `runmcd` field in `cloud-config`.  Perhaps this can be done either by editing my `swap.service` unit or perhaps by adding another `unit`, but I haven't figured out quite how.

So, that leaves me with two questions: (1) Can this be done or will it always be necessary to run the last commands manually?  (2) If the former, then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@cboettig - thanks to your unit file example and @philibaker note, I got this going - basically the only thing I had to do was to change the `ExecStartPre` to:

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "\
    fallocate -l 2g $SWAPFILE && \
    chmod 600 $SWAPFILE && \
    chattr +C $SWAPFILE && \
    mkswap $SWAPFILE && \
    losetup -f $SWAPFILE"
```

and that includes the entire setup in the preexec step.

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out in [this answer to an issue on Github](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-cloudinit/issues/156#issuecomment-47021274), you end up writing a unit to invoke the command of your choice. [This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/643088), gives a good example of using an arbitrary command:

```
#cloud-config 
....
coreos:
  units:
    - name: runcmd.service
      command: start
      content: |
        [Unit]
        Description=Creates a tmp foo file

        [Service]
        Type=oneshot
        ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "touch /tmp/foo;"
```